# Переход по ссылке при нажатии в combobox

Tags: html, php

Доброго всем времени суток, господа. Не хотел бы никого терзать, на ночь глядя, но у меня утро 8-)

```
echo "<select name=\"select\">
<option value=\"все\" selected>все</option>";
// while - echo "<option value=\"".$***."\">".$***."</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Внутри php кода идет вывод combobox, причем значения в цикле. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любой элемент списка был переход по ссылке? Естественно поскольку все добро работает внутри php кода, и ссылка будет с применением переменных, то совать туда js подобный код очень не хочется. Подскажите решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без JS не обойтись. Для удобства будем использовать ещё и jQuery.

Добавляем вместо value вставляете необходимый url:

```
// while - echo "<option value=\"".$item['url']."\">".$***."</option>";
```

И убираем value у пустой опции:

```
<option selected>все</option>";
```

Подключаем скрипт:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//так как change в некоторых IE иногда не срабатывает, повесим переход по url на click
    $('select[name=select]').click(function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {    
                    window.location = $(this).val();
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо, переход работает, но! нажмешь мышку и отжимать нельзя, при отжатии - переход. а хочется по выбирать. да и первый пункт жизненно необходим

Comment: не click, а change. Правда все равно плохо. Клавиатурой нельзя будет пользоваться - стрелка вниз будет переходить по первой/следующей ссылке.

Comment: согласен. автор конечно аццкий сотона, и респект ему, но все же код нужно чуть подправить